# How can I use non-breaking spaces in questions?

Tags: support, markdown, special-characters, whitespace

I want to use a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) on Stack Exchange to ensure that an important group of words is kept together on a single line.

I've tried inserting the character space directly as , but it doesn't seem to work properly.

**Is it possible to use non-breaking spaces on Stack Exchange?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that Stack Exchange *does* support non-breaking spaces. Google Chrome just has a tendency to auto-convert non-breaking spaces to normal spaces when copied.

You can insert non-breaking spaces   using the HTML codes `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`

You can also insert non-breaking hyphens `‑` with `&#8209;`