# Zero width non-breaking space removed from posts on edit

Tags: bug, edits, special-characters

I made a steganographic puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/find-the-hidden-message), which hides the message using the "zero width non-breaking space" character. But when I edited the question (to correct the tag), the non-breaking spaces disappeared, completely breaking the puzzle. I had rollback to the wrong tag to restore the non-breaking spaces.

I see no reason to remove non-breaking spaces, since it changes the formatting. Even if they were intended to be removed, that should happen on the initial submission, not only on edits.

Comment: Did you insert a literal non-breaking space into the post or did you use the `&nbsp;` HTML element? (not sure it's relevant, but I've never had a &nbsp; element removed from a post either (that I've seen) )

Comment: I entered the character itself.

Comment: I use unicode 00A0 and it's never been removed on edit.

Comment: I corrected the question, it's a "zero width non-breaking space", I didn't know that was different. And it's the point of the puzzle that the character is completely invisible. Does someone know a different character I can use until this bug is fixed?

Comment: Btw, update to the puzzle: I reverted back to the first version, that worked. But now of course the tag is wrong again.

Comment: Dammit, I just ran into this issue again, but with regular non-breaking spaces… Edit: At least this time I can work around it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298379/353011